# Connecting Parse-Server to Heroku

Tags: ios, heroku, server, parse-server

Hey I'm having trouble connecting my Parse-Server to my Heroku app. I've been following this: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server and I've done the first step for installing it locally by using `npm install -g parse-server mongodb-runner` which worked fine. However, the following steps to set up my AppID, MasterKey and MongoDB databaseURI don't work. I have all of these things already as I've used parse-server-example, however running this command `parse-server --appId APPLICATION_ID --masterKey MASTER_KEY --databaseURI mongodb://localhost/test` with the correct information hasn't worked for me, and I don't know what file to put my keys in. If someone could help me that would be very much appreciated as I just went in circles on this for 9+ hours today.
Thank you!

[When I try node index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgQcn.png)

[When I try npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Zdz.png)

[Cloud Code Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOb30.png)

Comment: what did you put in your index.js?

Comment: Everything that was in my index.js from my parse-server-example index.js folder.

Comment: Well then did you add a cloud code folder?

Comment: I feel like this could all be setup using the local or docker commands given in the README for the parse-server github, as there are no more specifications other than linking it to Heroku after that. However, these commands haven't worked for me for some reason

Comment: @GellertLee Added the cloud code folder and got a seemingly deeper, rooter error. Specified some of it above in screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You should put your keys in `index.js` file. To run parse server locally, you need to use `node index.js` in your command line.

If you want to connect to heroku, you need to make a `Procfile`(simply `touch Procfile`), then add `web: npm start` into the file.

After you push to Heroku, go to settings, reveal config vars, then put all your keys there.

[image]

Both `DATABASE_URI` and `MONDODB_URI` should be your mongodb url(not local). `SERVER_URL` should be the heroku app url.

Comment: in the past I've always put my keys in index.js, however for this Parse-Server the index.js doesn't have any fields to put the keys into. Should I add them myself? This index.js is also nested within a graphql folder. You can easily download the file yourself and have a look

Comment: I was wrong about it being nested within the graphql folder, it's actually nested within the lib folder within the parse-server folder, however it still doesn't include the fields necessary to put the keys in. Should I just add them?

Comment: Or maybe it's because I haven't connected my Heroku app yet and it's missing the folder for my app that includes the index.js file. That's how it was for my parse-server-example

Comment: @FinnWolff https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example download this repo and run `npm install`, then you'll have everything ready.

Comment: I can't use that repo because it isn't up to date at all, it doesn't include push notifications which is essential to what I need to do. It also hasn't been updated for 2 years which isn't good

Comment: Is there a way that I can just use https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server and link it to Heroku for my ios app?

Comment: @FinnWolff Then just add an `index.js` file in the root dir, then config the server there and run node.

Comment: @FinnWolff You can. just create index.js then push it to heroku. then follow what i just said in the answer.

Comment: Okay well it's failed when i've done node index.js and npm install, but I haven't added a Procfile yet. How and where do I go about adding that?

Comment: My npm-global folder that houses my parse-server and parse-desktop is also on my desktop, not sure if that's causing a problem or not.

Comment: @FinnWolff `touch Procfile` to make file. Can you explain the fail in slightly more detail please?

Comment: Okay check out my two screenshots above for each command failure